# Clockwise and counter-clockwise in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry

Can someone explain me how I can determine if a triangle is clockwise or counter-clockwise?

If I render a triangle with the following code

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
   glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
   glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
   glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
glEnd();
```

how do I now if it is clockwise or counter-clockwise? I do know that it also depends on the face of the triangle you are looking at, but how can I see that in the code? I have read that OpenGL uses counter-clockwise by default. But if I consider how OpenGL draws the vertices, it seems clockwise to me. I think it is just an error in my reasoning.

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Face_Culling

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glFrontFace.xhtml) saying:
The projection of a polygon to window coordinates is said to have clockwise winding if an imaginary object following the path from its first vertex, its second vertex, and so on, to its last vertex, and finally back to its first vertex, moves in a clockwise direction about the interior of the polygon.

It is important to consider the relation with the projection of said polygon to window coordinates.

Basically, your reasoning is slightly off when you say that OpenGL uses counter-clockwise by default. But for what? It is to determine what polygons are front - facing so that the polygons not visible are culled (not rendered). That is, there is some purpose for the winding, they don't just happen to be ccw or cw winded.

On a side node, stop using glBegin() and glEnd().

Comment: Actually, polygon primitives are always two-sided by nature. The winding order is used to determine which facet is being rasterized (front or back)... this is needed for things like culling, stencil, fixed-function lighting, polygon fill mode (pre-OpenGL 3), etc. You can see which side of a polygon-based (e.g. ***not*** line or point) primitive you are shading in a fragment shader using the pre-declared boolean: `gl_PolygonFrontFacing`, and as you pointed out, this is determined prior to rasterization by testing the post-projected winding of vertices.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman This is what I kinda... said? I don't understand what your point is, what did I say to claim otherwise, of course you're right.

Comment: Sorry, this was in response to your statement: "It is to determine what polygons are front-facing so that the polygons not visible are culled". The polygons themselves are not front-facing, think of them like cutouts of planes. You need a little bit of extra information to discern the front of a plane from the back (normal), in-lieu of normals OpenGL uses winding direction to determine which side of a polygon is being rasterized. But again, the polygon itself actually has two sides, there are no front-facing or back-facing polygons. It is actually **facet** culling and not **polygon culling**.

Comment: It is an important distinction, because prior to rasterization polygons do not have sides. Geometry shaders, for instance, do not emit a unique set of front- and back-facing primitives. It would be really cool if they did though ;)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Aaah, right, sorry, yes, I misspoke, thank you for the correction, I will try to reflect it in my answer. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

By default the glVertex3f function supplies the points in counter-clockwise order.

The points you have supplied visually form a clockwise triangle.

What you are seeing is the back face of the triangle.